# Range is not working when there is to many characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function, that is finding string ";" and replacing it with "$" but only if string ";" is in brackets, problem is, when there is to much text in cell, it doesn't work, I guess string only works with 255 characters max? Any way to work around this?

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, lb As Long, rb As Long, r As Range

Range("A1:A4").Copy Range("B1")

For Each r In Range("B1:B4")
    For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = "(" Then lb = lb + 1
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = ")" Then rb = rb + 1
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = ";" Then
            If lb > 0 And rb < lb Then r.Characters(i, 1).Text = "$"
        End If
    Next i
Next r

End Sub
```

EDIT:
If I set cell A1 to this text:

> text (it's ok; it's
> nhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh fzgh
> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
> hffffffffffffffffffffffffff hffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
> hjfghgfhfg  ot ok); ok (tekst;); ok

It doesn't work, but if it has less text like this, it works:

> text (it's ok; (ok;)it's not; ok);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in VBA are not limited to 255 characters, however, the `Range.Characters.Text` property is (though it's hard to find information about that).

But basically, you need `Range.Characters` only if you want to set format to single characters within a cell. In your case, it's better to do the string manipulation using a VBA string variable and write back the result into the cell. This not only avoids the 255 char problem, it's also faster.

Your code could look like this (didn't check if you logic itself is okay):

```
For Each r In Range("B1:B4")
    Dim s As String
    s = r.Value 

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) = "(" Then lb = lb + 1
        If Mid(s, i, 1) = ")" Then rb = rb + 1
        If Mid(s, i, 1) = ";" Then
            If lb > 0 And rb < lb Then
                Mid(s, i, 1) = "$"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    r.Value = s
Next r
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I've figure I should work with with String but got error in code and here you are with perfect solution, thanks! Still can't give vote, but selected it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `Replace` instead. Or you could dip into the murky world of regular expressions.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, lb As Long, rb As Long, r As Range

Range("A1:A4").Copy Range("B1")

For Each r In Range("B1:B4")
    For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = "(" Then lb = lb + 1
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = ")" Then rb = rb + 1
        If Mid(r, i, 1) = ";" Then
            If lb > 0 And rb < lb Then r = Application.Replace(r, i, 1, "$")
        End If
    Next i
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: If I use that code, I get error: "runtime error 13 type mismatch"

Comment: have you tried with the text from my original post (look at edit), first example, it doesn't work for me